# The character of the dual representation of a finite group.

Tags: finite-groups, solution-verification, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ a finite dimensional complex representation of $G$ with character $\chi:G \to \mathbb{C}$. I want to prove that the character of the dual representation is $\chi^*$, where $^*$ denotes complex conjugation.

Here is what I tried:

The dual representation is defined by $\rho^*:G \to GL(V^*)$ where $\rho(g):V^* \to V^*$ is the map
$$
\rho(g)(x^*) = x^* \circ \rho(g)^{-1}.
$$

Choose a $\rho$-invariant inner product $(-,-): V \times V \to \mathbb{C}$ **(I can make any inner product into a $\rho$ invariant one by averaging over $G$, but does a nondegenerate one always exist?)**

Let $g \in G$ and choose a basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of eigenvectors for $\rho(g)$, say $\rho(g)(e_i) = \lambda_i e_i$. Since the map $V \to V^*, \ v \mapsto (-,v)$ is an isomorphism, there is a basis $e_i^*$ for $V^*$ satisfying $e_i^*(v) = (v,e_i)$ for all $v \in V$. We compute the value of $\rho^*(g)$ on this basis:
\begin{align*}(\rho(g)(e_i^*))(v) & = e_i^* \circ \rho(g)^{-1}(v)\\
& = (\rho(g)^{-1}(v), e_i)\\
& = (v,\rho(g)(e_i)) & (\text{inner product is invariant})\\
& = (v,\lambda_ie_i)\\
& = \lambda_i^*(v,e_i)\\
& = \lambda_i^*e_i^*(v).
\end{align*}
Hence, the eigenvalues of $\rho^*(g)$ are $\lambda_1^*,\ldots,\lambda_n^*$. The character is the sum of the eigenvalues, so we have

\begin{align*}\chi_{\rho^*}(g) & = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^*\\
& = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)^*\\
&= \chi^*.
\end{align*}

It think my proof is correct, but would appreciate comments/suggestions.

Comment: A nondegenerate inner product exists on any finite-dimensional complex vector space: simply pick a basis and declare it to be orthonormal. After averaging, the result is clearly Hermitian, and nondegeneracy follows by positive-definiteness (which follows from positive-definiteness of the original inner product).

Comment: The proof looks good but it is a bit roundabout: there are shorter (or perhaps more modular) ways to get the same result. You can show that for any linear operator $T \colon V \to V$, the transpose operator $T^t \colon V^* \to V^*$ has the same eigenvalues as $T$ (which you did using a dual basis, though an inner product is not really required for this argument). When $T$ has finite order, each eigenvalue lies on the unit circle, so $\lambda^{-1} = \lambda^*$ for each eigenvalue, correspondingly the trace of $T^{-1}$ is the complex conjugate of the trace of $T$.